# How do you parse a HTML table representing time?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I am attempting to parse [this HTML table](http://www.bom.gov.au/jsp/ncc/cdio/weatherData/av?p_nccObsCode=122&p_display_type=dailyDataFile&p_startYear=2014&p_c=-1481845983&p_stn_num=086077) representing a year's worth of temperature data, provided by an Australian government website.

This table is set up in an unusual way: the columns are months, and the rows are days of the month (so the first row's cells are JAN 1, FEB 1, MAR 1). Each cell contains a number if there's data recorded for that day, an empty cell if no data was recorded, or a cell class `notDay` if the day does not exist (eg Feb 31st).

My intent is to build a database full of this data in the format

```
DATE            RAINFALL        MAX TEMP
2015-02-07        35                31
2015-02-07        40                17
```

My question is: what would the simplest or most efficient (in terms of programmer efficiency) way to parse the table to get the data into a usable format?

I'm personally using Ruby with the Nokogiri library, but general non-language-specific algorithm/approach advice is welcome if it makes for a better discussion. I'm not looking for someone to write the code and solve the problem for me, but for advice about the approach to take.

Comment: You do realize that on top of the page they offer a zip file that contains that very same data in CSV format already, which would be much easier to handle, no?

Comment: @CBroe I didn't, and now I feel really stupid. Thanks for pointing that out, though. I'll leave the question up anyway because working out how to parse things like this might still be useful information, even if it's unnecessary here.

Comment: D'oh! I never visited the source page. Lesson, kids: before you start scraping HTML, see if the data can be available in a better format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you can:

Take all the cells in the order they appear:

- Use `Array#flatten`  if you've got an array-of-array situation.

Discard any `notDay` cells with `Array#reject`

Iterate over all the relevant dates using a date range:

```
(Date.new(2014,1,1) .. Date.new(2014,12,31)).each {...}
```

And go from there...?

Comment: Clever and simple, I wouldn't have thought of that!